# Daily page ratio MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a cookie to track website traffic, which is then written to a database.

I am trying to get the daily ratio of my landing page index.php and the average of all the other pages to display in a Chart.

I am struggling with the syntax of the MySQL query.

I want 2 values from the query: $row->day and $pageRatio and to show these values for the past 30 days.

My database consists of one table called `tracking` with the following fields: id, cid, referrerDomain, referrer, page, ip, reverseIP, userAgent, lang, date

The page field contains the web page names eg: index.php, other.php etc.

```
$sql = "SELECT (
                 SELECT COUNT(`page`) FROM `tracking`
                 WHERE `page` = 'index.php'
                 AND DISTINCT(`date`)
                 GROUP BY DATE(`date`) ) AS indexCount,

             (
             SELECT COUNT(`page`) FROM `tracking`
             WHERE `page` != 'index.php' 
             AND `date`
             BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
             AND NOW()
             GROUP BY DATE(`date`) ) AS otherPageCount,

                 DATE(`date`) AS day
                 FROM `tracking`
                 WHERE `date`
                 BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
                 AND NOW()
                 GROUP BY DATE(`date`)";

      $sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql); 

      if($sqlprep->execute()) {
                $completedAmount = 0;
          while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                $pageRatio = $row->indexCount / $row->otherPageCount;

                echo "['" . $row->day . "', " . $pageRatio . "],\n";

           }

         }
```

The solution I found is an accepted answer here: [How do I combine these 3 queries into one MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294023/how-do-i-combine-these-3-queries-into-one-mysql-query#19294111)

```
SELECT DATE(`date`),
       COUNT(`page`) AS indexCount, 
       SUM(`page` = 'index.php') as idx_count, 
       SUM(`page` <> 'index.php') as not_idx_count
FROM `tracking`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Comment: show create table statement needed and example data   maybe even use sqlfriddle for this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have edited my question to include the structure. It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Let's start with the (first) error you're getting.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(`date`) GROUP BY DATE(`date`) ) AS indexCount, ' at line 4

Comment: use this http://sqlfiddle.com/ for the tables and example data use the left column for creats/insert    click build schema and copy and paste the url here...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry I am not familiar with sqlfiddle

Comment: SQLfriddle isn't that hard but you should really calculate ratio's in MySQL and not in PHP.. and your ratio calculation is wierd  all index.php pages vs an 30 day interval non index.php pages sounds an bit unnatural to me..

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, do not sure what you're trying to achieve there

Comment: Why not use something like Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will also work

```
SELECT DATE(`date`),
       COUNT(`page`) AS indexCount, 
       SUM(`page` = 'index.php') as idx_count, 
       SUM(`page` <> 'index.php') as not_idx_count
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,date,now()) as days
FROM `tracking` GROUP BY DATE(`date`) having days <30
```