# How do I combine these 3 queries into one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Each of the below queries gives me exactly what I want as a result individually, but I want to combine them into one query.

I want to output 3 colums: $row->day, $row->otherPageCount, $row->indexCount

There is one table `tracking` that contains all the data.

1).

```
SELECT COUNT(`page`) AS indexCount FROM `tracking`
WHERE `page` = 'index.php'
AND `date`
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

2).

```
SELECT COUNT(`page`) AS otherPageCount FROM `tracking`
WHERE `page` != 'index.php'
AND `date`
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

3).

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS day FROM `tracking`
WHERE `date`
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)
AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(`date`),
       COUNT(`page`) AS indexCount, 
       SUM(`page` = 'index.php') as idx_count, 
       SUM(`page` <> 'index.php') as not_idx_count
FROM `tracking`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IF for this:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), 
  SUM( IF( `page` = 'index.php', 1, 0 ) ) indexCount, 
  SUM( IF( `page` != 'index.php', 1, 0 ) ) otherPageCount
FROM `tracking`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

[juergen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19294063/327563) does the same thing, but makes the IF implicit. If you understand how it works, that's the better answer.